# move zeros in an array to the end

Tags: c++

"The question comes under a broad category of "Array Transformation". This category is the meat of tech interviews. Mostly because arrays are such a simple and easy to use data structure. Traversal or representation doesn't require any boilerplate code and most of your code will look like the Pseudocode itself.

The 2 requirements of the question are:

Move all the 0's to the end of array.

All the non-zero elements must retain their original order."

My thinking:
to find the zeros and exchange their positions with the last numbers

```
       /* int swap;
       int n=nums.size()-1;
       for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i--){
           if(nums[i]==0){
               swap = nums[i];
               nums[i] = nums[n];
               nums[n] = swap;
               n--;
           }

       }
```

My input
[0,1,0,3,12]
Output
[1,3,12,0,0]
Diff
Expected
[1,3,12,0,0]

And I did not know why the correct answer(the part) is :

```
 (int n = 0, cur = 0; cur < nums.size(); cur++) {
        if (nums[cur] != 0) {
            swap(nums[n++], nums[cur]);
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: sry my i-- means i++ there

Comment: You can edit your question and fix it.

Comment: You can edit your question. There is a link "edit" on the left-hand side below the question and above the comment section.

Comment: Your algorithm does not produce `[1, 3, 12, 0, 0]`, it produces `[12, 1, 3, 0, 0]`.

Comment: Have you tried walking through the correct version by hand, keeping track of how the variables and contents of the array/vector change in each iteration of the loop so you can visualize how it works?

Answer (score 4):

Can you use the standard library? [`std::stable_partition()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) makes it trivial. Something like

```
std::stable_partition(nums.begin(), nums.end(),
    [](const auto &n){ return n != 0; });
```

---

For the question of how the solution in your post works:

At the start of the first iteration, n is 0, cur is 0, and nums is [0,1,0,3,12]. `nums[cur]` is 0, so nothing happens. At the start of the second iteration, cur is 1, and `nums[cur]` is 1, so the swap and increment of n happens.

Now n is 1, cur is 2, and nums is [1,0,0,3,12]. `nums[cur]` is 0, so nothing happens in the third iteration. In the fourth iteration, with cur now 3, a swap happens. So at the start of the the fifth iteration, n is 2, cur is 4, and nums is [1,3,0,0,12]. I'll leave it to you to work out what happens in that step.

Basically, when n is not equal to cur, it's the index of a 0 element that can be swapped with a non-0 element that cur is the index of. This swapping eventually moves all 0's to the end.

Answer (score 0):

My take on the problem, minimal std library usage.  Probably not the most efficient, but it does the trick.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int src[]  = { 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 12 };           // Output: 1 3 12  0 0 0   check
            // = { 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 12, 0, 5 };  // Output: 3 1 12 5 0 0 0 0 0   check 

    int n = sizeof(src) / sizeof(src[0]);

    for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
        for (int y = x + 1; y < n; y++) {
            if (src[x] == 0 && src[y] != 0) {
                int swap = src[x];
                src[x] = src[y];
                src[y] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << src[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Once you have made a swap, `src[x] != 0`, and so you can always skip the rest of the inner loop, meaning that you can add a `break;` at the end of the `if` block. Then you also know that all `src[y] != 0` for all previous values of `y`, meaning that retesting them in the inner loop is unnecessary, i.e. you can move the initialization `int y = x+1` outside the two loops (making it `int y = 0`) and not reset it in each iteration of the outer loop. Then your algorithm will have worst-case linear time complexity in the array length, while currently it has average-case quadratic one.